# Want my code to raise a specific type or error, but print the orginal error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

So suppose I have some code that raises any type or error. I want my code instead to raise an AssertionError, but print out the original message of that would have been printed with the original error. How would I do that?

(example)

original error: 
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

custom error: AssertionError: exception = TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to catch the exception raised and then raise whichever type you'd like. Since you mentioned wanting to catch *any* type of error you would have to use the `Exception` class as your catch.

However, I would note that this is generally bad practice because you typically want to only catch specific errors that you anticipate having. But if you end up throwing an error anyways, i suppose its not terrible. But also make me wonder specifically what the goal of this code is. Anyways..

**catch anything**

`try...except Exception as e`

**raise preferred error**

`raise AssertionError()`

**get the message**

`e.message`

**get the type**

`type(e)`

**Putting it all together:**

```py
try:
    # some code that raises an error
    g = 10 + '11'
except Exception as e:
    raise AssertionError('{}: {}'.format(type(e), e.message))
```

The output would be:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

This could be cleaned up to get rid of the ugly output of the `type(e)` but in general this is how you would include the type of error as well as its corresponding message.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped, but I also would like to know what the original type of error was.  Here, the original one was a TypeError, so how would I know that?

Comment: oh yea, you can use the `type(e)` to access that. I'll edit the answer to include that.

Comment: also @J_H has a much cleaner solution. I believe that functionality is specific to Python 3, but thats the version you tagged, so i would go with that

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [`from` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html) (introduced in Python 3) that lets you wrap an app-specific exception around a base exception.
Here is an example:

```
>>> try:
...     1 > '1'
... except TypeError as e:
...     raise AssertionError() from e
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
AssertionError
```

You can supply a string containing a diagnostic message when you create a new exception.
It would be better to define your own app-specific exception(s), rather than recycling AssertionError.
If you define several, make one of them the [grand]parent and have other exceptions inherit from that ancestor.
That allows callers to conveniently catch fine- or coarse-grained classes of errors.

There's a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) that describes further considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can hide original traceback by setting `__suppress_context__ = True` and make some formatting to fit your needs of expected output:

```
try:
    a = '1' > 1
except Exception as exc:
    assertion_exc = AssertionError('exception = {}: {}'.format(type(exc).__name__, str(exc)))
    assertion_exc.__suppress_context__ = True # comment this line to see full traceback
    raise assertion_exc
```

Full output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./file.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise assertion_exc
AssertionError: exception = TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: I would like my exception to be more general. In my example, TypeError was just an example of one of the possible types of errors. So how could I encompass any type of error?

Comment: `except Exception` will catch anything. Updated my answer.